# vb.net option strict on convert string to date

Tags: vb.net, date

I am trying to convert a string from a database to a Date type with this format "yyyy-M-d"
The string is stored in this format "yyyy-M-d"
So I can execute this code with the Date variables in this format "yyyy-M-d"
Because Option Strict is ON Visual Studio 2019 ver 16.7.5 is UN-happy

```
If gvTorF = "False" And varToday > varFTue Then
```

First I am not sure it is necessary but the posts I read about comparing Dates makes this suggestion
Here are my variables

```
Dim varToday As Date
Dim varFTue As Date
Dim varStr As String
```

Next I click a Button to get the data from the Database With this code below

```
Public Sub GetDateInfo()
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand($"SELECT * FROM DateInfoTable WHERE DID = '1'", conn)
            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While rdr.Read()
                    varTorF = rdr("ditORf").ToString
                    'varFTue = CDate(rdr("diTESTdate")) 'shows as 10/26/2021
                    'varFTue = Date.ParseExact(varStr, "yyyy-M-d", provider As IFormatProvider, As Date)
                    'Tried line of code above this can NOT format correct 
                    varTESTdate = CType(rdr("diTESTdate"), String) 'shows as 2021-10-26
                End While
                rdr.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Other than turning Option Strict OFF or just use the format "M-d-yyyy" to run my test
Where varToday > varFTue which seems to work
**The Question is what are my other options to make the conversion from String to Date?**

The function below will convert the two Strings varTESTdate & varTodayStr
The varTESTdate is from the database and varTodayStr is created in the function bothDates
Here is the Function and the call made behind a Button Click event

```
bothDates(varTESTdate, varTodayStr)

Public Function bothDates(ByVal varTESTdate As String, ByVal varTodayStr As String) As Object
    result1 = Date.ParseExact(varTESTdate, "yyyy-M-d", provider:=Nothing)
    Dim dateToday = Date.Today
    varTodayStr = dateToday.ToString("yyyy-M-d")
    result2 = Date.ParseExact(varTodayStr, "yyyy-M-d", provider:=Nothing)
    Return (result1, result2)
End Function
```

Comment: @HansPassant that is nice but the word provider shows as RED when I convert it to vb.net and I am not sure how to fix that intelisense not offering usable suggestion Any ideas ? my ParseExact did the same thing

Comment: @HansPassant Got the code converted to vb.net but "result" looks like it is a date to view it I had to use result.ToString to put it in a TextBox  will keep testing thanks

Comment: If I came upon your code professionally, I would be confused by variable names, as I am now. `varTorF` and `varStr` are cryptic. Use real words to describe what the thing is. Like `testDateString` when it's a string and `testDate` when it's a date.

Comment: The date comparison method is `date1.CompareTo(date2)` and will return an integer, negative, 0, or equal, indicating whether date1 is >, =, < date2

Comment: @djv it's more readable to just compare datetime as if they were numbers `If startTime > endTime Then throw new Exception("You have your dates the wrong way round")` - don't use compareto to turn two dates into one number that you then compare with another number to decided what to do..

Comment: I didn't understand the part where you were talking about your date being yyyy-M-d and then suddenly said you use M-d-yyyy

Comment: @djv I agree the format sucks but I tossed this together just for testing YES I looked at CompareTo Just wanted to use > as I am testing two dates against fourth Tuesday and End of Month Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the conversion in your code already

```
Dim d = DateTime.ParseExact("2026-10-26", "yyyy-M-d", Nothing) 'or provide a culture instead of Nothing..
```

Though I'm not sure what the trailing "As IFormatProvider, As Date" is there for

```
    'varFTue = Date.ParseExact(varStr, "yyyy-M-d", provider As IFormatProvider, As Date)
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is a syntax error in this context in vb, and looks like a remnant artifact of a conversion from C# where we use "as X" to perform casts. Don't assume that converters get all code perfect all the time; you nearly always have to fix up their output, especially if pasting in only parts of a program where they can't see all the declared variables (your code appears to not contain `provider` as a variable)

Comment: I did get the code to work with this format             Dim Provider As IFormatProvider = Nothing
            result1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString1, format, Provider)

            varFTue = result1
            tbDateTwo.Text = result1.ToString("yyyy-M-d") I test how it works but at this time just using this format seems to work 10/8/2021 > 10/26/2021 not sure why the recommendation to use "yyyy-M-d" ? ? thank you

Comment: In the very first lines of your question said you store dates in format yyyy-M-d; this is why I used that format in my recommendation. You are free to change it accordingly